# Redis - Cache entry evictions across multiple databases

Tags: redis

When using multiple databases on a single redis instance and its memory is full, when I'm trying to insert new data it samples a number of keys and it applies an algorithm to them to determine which ones should be evicted.

But, if I'm using db0 and db1 and I'm trying to insert a new record into db1, will redis sample keys from the same database or does it sample them globally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it does eviction, Redis chooses eviction candidate from all databases.

In your case, it might evict keys from db0 or db1.

Comment: May I ask for a source that confirms this

Comment: Check the `performEvictions` function in evict.c